# get hot or get cold

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-usage

> Sometimes he **gets hot** with his girlfriend. Other times he **gets cold** with her to get her to come to like him more.

Is this the right expression?

For example, at first he spent much time dating her. Later he spent less time dating her. Actually, he loves her a lot. He wants her to love him more. On purpose, he pretends he is losing interest in her. He thinks such tantalizing strategy has a good effect on the romantic relationship. As a result, she can't help doing nice things to him more than before in order to recover their relationship.

Comment: Are you writing a Mills & Boon romance, or doing something else?

Answer (score 1):

"Gets hot" and "gets cold" don't really work here. What you are trying to convey is that he sometimes behaves warmly towards her, and sometimes behaves coldly, or "gives her the cold shoulder". There are various shades and nuances, but warm and cold behavior is a good start. He can turn on the warmth, for example, or act coldly, become icy or frosty etc. etc.

Comment: Concur. Good answer. The OP might consider "Sometimes he treated his girlfriend warmly; at other times, he treated her coldly to get her to like him more."